# List content not visible in Android ArrayAdapter example

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to learn Android ArrayAdapter from Udacity's Android's Multiscreen app course. I've done everything as it has mentioned in the course but can't able to see the list view. Also, not getting any error from the android studio.

Here are my codes-

**NumbersActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        // Create a list of words
        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

        words.add(new Word("one","lutti"));
        words.add(new Word("two","otikko"));
        words.add(new Word("three","tolokooosu"));
        words.add(new Word("four","oyyisa"));
        words.add(new Word("five","massokka"));
        words.add(new Word("six","temmokka"));
        words.add(new Word("seven","kenakaku"));
        words.add(new Word("eight","kawinta"));
        words.add(new Word("nine","woe"));
        words.add(new Word("ten","naaaache"));


        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**WordAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by opsol on 15/7/16.
 */
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getmMiwokTranslation());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

**Word.java**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

/**
 * Created by opsol on 15/7/16.
 */
public class Word {
    private String mDefaultTranslation;
    private String mMiwokTranslation;

    public Word(String mDefaultTranslation, String mMiwokTranslation){
        mDefaultTranslation = mDefaultTranslation;
        mMiwokTranslation = mMiwokTranslation;
    }

    public String getDefaultTranslation(){
        return mDefaultTranslation;
    }

    public String getmMiwokTranslation(){
        return mMiwokTranslation;
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lutti" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_numbers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity">

</ListView>
```

**Screenshot of my list view** -

[image]

Anyone help me to understand what's wrong at here ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Word class constructor should look like this

```
public Word(String mDefaultTranslation, String mMiwokTranslation) {
        this.mDefaultTranslation = mDefaultTranslation;
        this.mMiwokTranslation = mMiwokTranslation;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked. But, what was the error? Because, before this also I've seen at many places it's not necessary to `this` to access object property in Java. Even, Android Studio also was not showing any kind of syntax error.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=144 check this link please!

Comment: Got it. Thanks for this info.